# First data point not considered in R timeSeries when averaging using `aggregate()`; how to correctly employ the function?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I want to construct daily averages for hourly electricity prices from the NordPool market. I am using the `aggregate()` method from the `timeSeries` package to construct the daily means from this hourly data, which I've converted to a `timeSeries` object. Here is a `dput()` of the first 72 hours:

```
    > dput(tstSeries)
    new("timeSeries"
    , .Data = structure(c(31.05, 30.47, 28.92, 27.88, 26.96, 27.84, 28.79, 
28.63, 28.44, 28.3, 30.65, 31.55, 32.16, 32.45, 32.63, 33.65, 
34.9, 36.22, 36.65, 36.37, 35.49, 34.41, 34.66, 32.55, 33.15, 
32.66, 31.83, 31.47, 32.56, 34.36, 36.28, 38.39, 39.09, 38.33, 
38.42, 38.25, 37.96, 37.89, 37.88, 38.78, 39.83, 39.91, 39.32, 
38.49, 37.46, 36.94, 36.37, 34.59, 33.11, 32.22, 31.46, 31.67, 
32.05, 33.67, 34.93, 35.82, 36.38, 36.52, 36.71, 36.6, 36.51, 
36.4, 36.42, 36.58, 36.94, 36.94, 36.81, 36.43, 35.91, 35.45, 
34.77, 32.09), .Dim = c(72L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "TS.1"))
    , units = "TS.1"
    , positions = c(1356998400, 1357002000, 1357005600, 1357009200, 1357012800, 
1357016400, 1357020000, 1357023600, 1357027200, 1357030800, 1357034400, 
1357038000, 1357041600, 1357045200, 1357048800, 1357052400, 1357056000, 
1357059600, 1357063200, 1357066800, 1357070400, 1357074000, 1357077600, 
1357081200, 1357084800, 1357088400, 1357092000, 1357095600, 1357099200, 
1357102800, 1357106400, 1357110000, 1357113600, 1357117200, 1357120800, 
1357124400, 1357128000, 1357131600, 1357135200, 1357138800, 1357142400, 
1357146000, 1357149600, 1357153200, 1357156800, 1357160400, 1357164000, 
1357167600, 1357171200, 1357174800, 1357178400, 1357182000, 1357185600, 
1357189200, 1357192800, 1357196400, 1357200000, 1357203600, 1357207200, 
1357210800, 1357214400, 1357218000, 1357221600, 1357225200, 1357228800, 
1357232400, 1357236000, 1357239600, 1357243200, 1357246800, 1357250400, 
1357254000)
    , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    , FinCenter = "GMT"
    , recordIDs = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")
    , title = "Time Series Object"
    , documentation = "Wed May 20 11:02:09 2015"
)
```

To do the averaging, I do the following:

```
## daily averaging
bydaily = timeSequence(from = start(tstSeries), to = end(tstSeries), by = "day")
tstSeries.daily = aggregate(tstSeries, by = bydaily, FUN = mean)
```

The output I get is:

```
tstSeries.daily

>GMT
TS.1
2013-01-01 31.05000
2013-01-02 31.82167
2013-01-03 36.67375
```

Here, the first daily averaged value is the original data point! I performed the same calculation in Excel and confirmed that the first data point is not being considered in the averaging operation, instead the average for 2013-01-02 is being calculated as the average of 2013-01-01 01:00 to 2013-01-02 00:00.

I've seen several examples demonstrating the use of `aggregate()` but have not come across any which raise this issue. Has anyone seen this happen and is there a work-around?

Comment: I am just wondering whether `aggregate` from `timeSeries` is designed for this kind of calculation.

Comment: @Pascal I would presume it is; the help files give an example: `## Aggregate by Weeks - 
   by <- timeSequence(from = start(x),  to = end(x), by = "week")
   aggregate(x, by, mean)`

Comment: @avg In your case, it is hour to day. Is `timeSeries` designed for this?

Comment: @Pascal I can't be sure, but in the example provided they've done weekly averages on daily data, and I'm wondering why it should matter if I want to go from hourly to daily. And in my case, the code is averaging the _correct_ no. of hours, only that the first record is being omitted somehow. I'd like to know what's going on from someone who's had more experience with this..

Comment: @ArunRaja I gave it a thought but I do not have much experience with `dplyr`, and none using it for time-series. I always seem to confuse myself when using it even otherwise. Do you have some references or examples of it being used for such a purpose? I do not see many questions on that on SO..Thanks.

Comment: How about using `apply.rolling` function from `PerformanceAnalytics` packahe? you can apply mean over 24 intervals. If can post a code that gives you the desired output if you wish.

Comment: Thanks @AhmedSalhin. I just checked the documentation and if I'm not mistaken, `apply.rolling` is strictly for a rolling window with no way to make it 'jump' over days. In any case, it would be helpful if you can post a solution!

Comment: The argument `by` in the function allows you to 'jump' over intervals. I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that returns the desired output. It depends on `apply.rolling` function from `PerformanceAnalytics` package.

```
tstSeries.daily<-apply.rolling(tstSeries,width=24,by=24, FUN="mean") # get the mean of each of the 24 hours intervals.
tstSeries.daily<-tstSeries.daily[complete.cases(tstSeries.daily),] # remove rows with NAs.
rownames(tstSeries.daily)<-as.Date(rownames(tstSeries.daily)) # remove the time part of the index.
print(tstSeries.daily)
GMT 
              calcs
2013-01-01 31.73417
2013-01-02 36.67542
2013-01-03 35.09958
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well! Is there a reason why you did not suggest using `apply.daily` instead? And if I want to do monthly, weekly or quarterly averages, I imagine I could use the corresponding `apply.foo()` methods?

Comment: @avg Definitely `apply.daily` will do the job for your case. Also, it saves the second line in my answer. I just get used to `apply.rolling` as it gives me more freedom to specify the width I need and ignoring some periods of the data I am not interested in.